# Trying to access x.IndexOf(x); getting "no overload for method IndexOf takes '1' arguments"

Tags: c#

I can't seem to figure out why I keep getting this error.

> No overload for method IndexOf takes '1' arguments

Here's the code and error:

[image]

Comment: @isi: it's not a duplicate of that question...

Comment: Please post the code as text instead of an image so it can be searched properly.

Comment: @MitchWheat the OP gets the compile error similar as in the linked question and asks why. The answer tries to depict why the other OP gets the compiler error. Probably this question's OP wants to achieve something different, but this seems a bit unclear if so.

Answer (score 10):

`Array.IndexOf` is a *static* method, meaning you call it on the `Array` class itself instead of an instance, so the proper syntax would be:

```
int ender = Array.IndexOf(inList, ";")
```

It's interesting that the compiler *tries* to bind it to `Array.IndexOf` and does not find a static method with only one argument, hence the error message.  The *real* problem would have been clearer if you had used the correct number of arguments, in which case you'd get the message

> Member `'System.Array.IndexOf<T>(T[], T)'` cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: Had this problem when I upgrade Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI